# Keep ul (unordered list) in a fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have left menu, which is a ul, and I want it to be static on the screen. When I scroll, the full menu should always appear. Is there any way I can manage this.

I tried to set the 'position: fixed; top: 0, left: 0' but it shifts the div that is next to the ul, on top of the ul.

```
<div>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<ul class='anvbar-nav'>
    <!-- ...some other stuff-->
</ul>

<!-- Content Wrapper -->
<div class='content'>
    <!-- ...some other stuff-->
</div>
```

I want to have the ul on the top left side in a fixed position. But when I add the 'position: fixed' to the ul, the div with content shifts on top of the ul. How can I fix this issue. I want to content div to occupy the remaining space that is left on the screen, and not go on top of the left menu (ul)

Comment: Can you create a snippet along with the CSS too? Also, add the list items `li` in your `ul`s

Comment: Show more code? Put the HTML is a snippet by clicking the little page icon with `< >` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify left navigation width and give the same value as margin-left to the content div.
See the snippet.

```css
:root {--leftnavwidth :250px;}

ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}
li{
padding:10px 20px;
}


.anvbar-nav{
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:var(--leftnavwidth);
 background:#564897;
 color:#fff;
 height:100%;
}
.content{
margin-left:var(--leftnavwidth);
}
```

```html
<div>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<ul class='anvbar-nav'>
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li>Menu item 2</li>
   <li>Menu item 3</li>
   <li>Menu item 4</li>
   <li>Menu item 5</li>
   <li>Menu item 6</li>
   <li>Menu item 7</li>
</ul>

<!-- Content Wrapper -->

<div class='content'>
<h2>Content Wrappe</h2>
 <p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 
  <p>
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check in w3schools also @ https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp

With Full height to the leftnav

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

With Auto Height to  the left nav

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #2196F3;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #064579;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 140px; /* Same width as the sidebar + left position in px */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Auto Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is as tall as its content (the links), and is always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add wrappers to the elements, making the individual items scrollable. If you use flexbox, you can even make it regardless of the menu width!

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 12px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 12px;
}

.wrapper > .content {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class='navbar-wrapper'>
  <ul class='navbar-nav'>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Of</li>
    <li>Many</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Items</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Content Wrapper -->
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>
    Some stuff that we don't want to overlap, because this is the content
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```